# Can I save both card and bank account details when taking a payment through Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to make some changes to a payment gateway (Stripe) and its integration with Docusign.

The payments are for an ongoing service.

We currently allow the customer to enter their card details in Docusign when they sign the contract. The card is then charged on a monthly basis.

In order to reduce costs, we'd like to change this, so the first payment to be made via a credit / debit card, and any subsequent payments to be made via Direct Debit, using the customer's bank account details.

Ideally, all of the payment data will be taken whilst the user is still on the Docusign site, rather than when they return to our site after signing the contract.

We currently save the card and use it to make future payments by adding the `paymentOption: 'save_and_authorize'` option to the paymentDetails object in the formula tab in the envelope args but I'm not sure if it's possible to also request the direct debit details at the same time - does anyone know if this can be done?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What payment processing provider do you use?

Comment: We are using Stripe

Comment: Stripe may be able to do this then, not DocuSign

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible to do that. During the signing ceremony, the customer has only the possibility to select either [payment by credit card](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=juu1573854950452&topicId=jgm1573854948438.html&_LANG=enus) or by [bank account](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=juu1573854950452&topicId=xqi1573854946984.html&_LANG=enus) (ACH or SEPA), but not both.
You can also refer to our [Payment FAQ](https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/DocuSign-Payments-FAQ?language=en_US&rsc_301).
Basically this kind of question should be managed by our eSignature team. For double verification, if you want, you can also raise a ticket to them through our Docusign support center.